# Редактирование отрывка из статьи

Tags: грамотная-речь, стилистика, тавтология

*Обзор предстоящих культурных событий*

"Фестиваль авторской песни "Балтийские струны" открыт для авторов, пишущих песни и исполняющих их под собственный аккомпанемент. Языковых барьеров нет! Музыка не знает границ! Гостей фестиваля ждёт песня с хорошей поэзией, музыкой, исполненная под гитару."

Общий смысл отрывка понятен, но текст какой-то корявый, "дискомфортный".

Помогите, пожалуйста, с редактированием.  Буду признательна за каждое разъяснение.

Comment: Зачем здесь лозунги: "Языковых барьеров нет!", "Музыка не знает границ!"? Ожидаются песни на разных языках, авторы или гости из разных стран? Тогда укажите это, например : "Фестиваль открыт для авторов и гостей из разных стран".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У нас авторская песня открыта для авторов (это первая "дискомфортность");

гостей ждёт песня в количестве одной штуки (это вторая);

песня с хорошей поэзией (м-да, третьей будет);

"исполняющих" и "исполненная" - слишком близко друг от друга!

Если первая песня (которая авторская) упомянута в широком смысле, [метонимически](http://videotutor-rusyaz.ru/uchenikam/teoriya/328-vyrazitelnyesredstvaleksiki3.html), то у второй нет причин оставаться в единственном числе.

Корректорские замечания: точки внутри кавычек не бывает, если закрывающей кавычке не предшествует сокращенное слово;

в коротком тексте нежелательны кавычки одного начертания.

Как редактор, я бы дала читающему передышку в восклицательных знаках, для чего достаточно дать "воздух" тексту простой перестановкой предложений и дроблением на абзацы:

---

«Фестиваль авторской песни "Балтийские струны" открыт для всех, кто пишет песни и дарит их слушателям под собственный аккомпанемент.

Гостей фестиваля ждут песни - хорошие стихи и музыка, - спетые под гитару.

Языковых барьеров нет!

Музыка не знает границ!»

---

Другие филологи "услышат" текст по-другому.

Меня самоё смущает "дарит их слушателям"... Предлагает?

Comment: А мне очень понравилось "дарит их слушателям". Использовал в своем ответе без разрешениея автора. Надеюсь быть прощенным :)

Comment: @Galina Avanesova, Ваши корректорские замечения безупечны. С "разнокалиберными" кавычками  мне пока в клавиатуре никак не разобраться.

Comment: Римма! Можно погуглить, какое сочетание клавиш даёт кавычки-«ёлочки», а можно просто копировать из любого текста, где они есть. https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B8

Comment: М_Г! Вы великодушно прощены автором! )))

Answer (score 1):

**Вариант текста:**

Фестиваль авторской песни "Балтийские струны" открыт для всех, кто пишет  песни и исполняет их под собственный аккомпанемент. Нет языковых барьеров  и искусство не знает границ! Гостей фестиваля ждёт встреча с хорошей поэзией и музыкой, исполненной на гитаре.

Comment: _музыка, исполненная **под** гитару_? Музыку _на_ гитаре исполняют (в оригинале - "песня... под гитару"). Если ещё только ждёт, то лучше "исполняемая", чем "исполненная", напр.: 
_Гостей фестиваля ждут песни, исполняемые под гитару, с хорошей музыкой и поэтичными текстами._

Comment: Спасибо, я исправила текст. Мне  кажется, что в данном случае при правке надо было максимально сохранить стиль и объем авторского варианта.

Answer (score 1):

Написано без души, это понятно. Но дискомфорт как таковой у меня вызывает только последняя строчка, в частности то, что "исполненная под гитару" оторвано от "песни". Остальное очень субъективно и зависит от назначения этого призыва. Если место позволяет, то да, не мешает разорвать на несколько абзацев для "броскости". Если нет - и так сойдет. Разъяснение "пишущих и исполняющих" пожалуй, лишнее. Ну кто не знает, что такое авторская песня? А кто и не знает, тому все равно не интересно.

Вариант:

***"Фестиваль авторской песни "Балтийские струны"!!!

Открыт для авторов, исполняющих свои песни под свою музыку!

Языковых барьеров нет! Музыка не знает границ!***

***Гостей фестиваля ждет песня под гитару, с хорошей поэзией и музыкой.***

Последнюю фразу крутил так и этак - все равно коряво, какие-то чужие тут слова про музыку и поэзию. Но так получше, вроде.

Повторюсь, для идеального текста тут нужно быть "сильно в теме" того, чего ради зазывалочка пишется, целевую, так сказать, аудиторию чувствовать и общий контекст.

Comment: А зачем так много восклицательных знаков???

Comment: "исполняющих **свои** песни под **свою** музыку" - зачем такой упор на "свое"?

Comment: @Morkovkin  Это кусочек текста из статьи "Обзор предстоящих культурных событий",  на текущий год,  на целую газетную страницу. Это не зазывалочка, это только один из ляпсусов, которых тьма.   Автор - специалист по культуре.

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова *Это кусочек текста из статьи...  Автор - специалист по культуре* - Да, сильно... Тогда рекламный стиль не пойдёт. Но боюсь, тут я ничего не присоветую, обзоры таким слогом не пишутся в принципе. Оставьте уж как есть, он же "спицилист". )))

Comment: @Morkovkin Дело в том, что эти экзерциции уже напечатаны. Я хотела узнать: не преувеличена ли моя "дискомфортность" в восприятии Великого, Русского...

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова Ясно. Но тогда надо было, наверно, и вопрос соответствующим образом задать... Впрочем, попробую ответить, хотя бы в комментариях. "Дискомфортность", полагаю, вещь часто очень субъективная. Объективно я тут вижу некоторое косноязычие в последней фразе, уже писал. А субъективно - зависит от многих факторов, даже вот, например, от статуса читающего. Я, как автор, всегда максимально на стороне пишущего, правлю только то, что нельзя не поправить. Поэтому и дискомфорта нет. А редактор-корректор-рецензент просто не может не поправить всё "под себя" .

Comment: Но если постараться от личного впечатления абстрагироваться, то в сухом остатке то, что таким языком обзоры (именно обзоры, не рекламные проспекты!) не пишут. Возможно именно это порождает дополнительный дискомфорт. Простите, вряд ли смогу добавить что-то. При том еще, что бываю тут набегами, в ближайшее время не ждите..

Answer (score 1):

Фестиваль авторской песни "Балтийские струны" открыт для гостей **из разных стран**. Для всех, кто пишет песни и дарит их слушателям под собственный аккомпанемент. Для всех, кто любит песни, исполненные под гитару. Языковых барьеров нет! Музыка не знает границ! Гости фестиваля получат удовольствие от хороших стихов, соединенных с хорошей музыкой. (Вариант: Гости фестиваля смогут оценить высокий уровень поэзии, соединенной с хорошей музыкой.)

Замечания:

- Я исходил из того, что важно подчеркнуть интернациональный характер фестиваля.
- Если будут звучать песни на разных языках, то не все, конечно, поймут слова, но этим можно пренебречь :)

Comment: Вы совершенно правы в в своих замечаниях.  Это будет международный  (возможно)  фестиваль в небольшом эстонском городке у самого Финского залива.